# What is the best method to code physical address in html?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c, web-standards

What is the best method to code physical address in html ? in Semantic, Accessible and SEO way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a **Microformats vCard**

```
<div class="vcard">
  <span class="fn">Gregory Peck</span>
  <a class="org url" href="http://www.commerce.net/">CommerceNet</a>
  <div class="adr">
    <span class="type">Work</span>:
    <div class="street-address">169 University Avenue</div>
    <span class="locality">Palo Alto</span>,  
    <abbr class="region" title="California">CA</abbr>  
    <span class="postal-code">94301</span>
    <div class="country-name">USA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
   <span class="type">Work</span> +1-650-289-4040
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
    <span class="type">Fax</span> +1-650-289-4041
  </div>
  <div>Email: 
   <span class="email">info@commerce.net</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Accesible**: √
**Semantic**: I guess..
**SEO**:  √ [Google announces support for microformats](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html)

More examples at http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-examples
Also check out the [Oomph Microformats toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Oomph) that helps you displaying and consuming microformats.

Comment: Do we need to write css for all classes in my CSS file? and in vcard where i can put company name? and what is the benefit of formatting like this ?

Comment: You don't need to add all the classes, only the ones that will help you displaying it in a nice way.

Comment: @Jitendra No. Classes are not required to have a specified style.

Comment: I think i will go for id in the onces that are not general.

Comment: +1 it seems best answer till now but i still have some confusion , in vcard where i can put company name? and what is the benefit of formatting like this ?

Comment: Use `fn` class in any element for the name, and `org` class for the company. You can put them together if you are showing a company address.

Comment: The mentioned Oomph toolkit has a tool to make them quickly

Answer (score -3):

`<address>` is exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.6

Comment: `address` is **not** exactly what you are looking for. `address` is intended only to mark up contact info regarding the currently viewd page (like the Apache 404 default error pages and the "Apache X.X at ..." line.

Comment: The W3C specifications : >The ADDRESS element may be used by authors to supply contact information for a document
It is not 'intended only'. I think the most important part is 'supply contact information', and it's what you should want when you provide an address. So it look semanticly correct to use `address` in those cases.

Comment: from HTML 5 Spec: The ´address´ element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information. 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-address-element