# Is Microformats vCard still a best semantic way to code "contact information", in HTML 5?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

Is Microformats still a best semantic way to code contact information in a web page?

[image]

I asked this question almost 2 years ago and got the answer where Microformat was the best solution. [What is the best method to code physical address in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886923/what-is-the-best-method-to-code-physical-address-in-html)

Now today in HTML 5, Is that still the best way?

```
<div class="vcard">
  <span class="fn">Gregory Peck</span>
  <a class="org url" href="http://www.commerce.net/">CommerceNet</a>
  <div class="adr">
    <span class="type">Work</span>:
    <div class="street-address">169 University Avenue</div>
    <span class="locality">Palo Alto</span>,  
    <abbr class="region" title="California">CA</abbr>  
    <span class="postal-code">94301</span>
    <div class="country-name">USA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
   <span class="type">Work</span> +1-650-289-4040
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
    <span class="type">Fax</span> +1-650-289-4041
  </div>
  <div>Email: 
   <span class="email">info@commerce.net</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (updating 2011 context for nowadays)    As showed by [this answer about Microformat *vs* Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28650129/287948) , after 2013 the scenarios changed and Microdata is the best choice...  This [recent statistical study](http://dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/fileadmin/lehrstuehle/ki/pub/Meusel-etal-Schema-org-Adoption-WIMS2015.pdf) reinforce the Microdata adoption. See also [tag schema.org here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema.org).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little bit different in HTML5, but builds on the same concept. See:

- Examples and info on what you'd like to do @ http://rachaelmoore.name/posts/design/html/html5-microdata-contact-info/
- The spec @ http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/

Comment: Is there any tool like this http://vcardmaker.com/ to make the code with newer HTML5 standards?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's extra complicated because it's trying to support both the current hcard/vcard and future html5 methods. I don't know of any tool like that to use though, sorry :/

Comment: Keep in mind the new http://www.schema.org thing that all the major search engines have thrown in on.  It utilizes HTML5 microdata exclusively and new vocabularies that bear some resemblance to http://www.microformats.org and http://www.data-vocabulary.org, but are also different and more extensive.  Also see http://ablognotlimited.com for info and http://rlmo.me/n7zNU0 for bookmarks that include tools (no HTML5 ones that I know of right now).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the "conversion" form that I am using, if it helps. (The first couple of sites I forgot the html5 doc tag, and spent an hour trying to find out why it wasn't working, the document elements aren't recognized if the doc type is wrong, duh!)

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization"> 
    <h2 itemprop="name">Heading2</h2>
    TEXT text text

    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
        <span itemprop="street-address">12345 test way </span>, 
        <span itemprop="locality">Testville</span>, 
        <span itemprop="region">TS</span> 
        <span itemprop="postal-code">00000</span>
    </div>
    <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Geo/" style="display:none"><!—Don’t display in UI-->
        <span itemprop="latitude">11.1111 N</span>  
        <span itemprop="longitude">11.1111 W</span>  
    </span>  
    <p>Call us at:</p> 
    <span itemprop="tel">555-555-5555</span>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.blahblahbla.com" itemprop="url"> http://www.blahblahbla.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

([Citation](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/Web-Developer-Tutorial-HTML5-Microdata-3920016.htm#fbid=5BR2GxRd_sh)).